# Is a fixed subgroup of a compact Lie group cotorally included in finitely many conjugacy classes?

Tags: lie-groups, torus

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group, in the next discussion we consider only its closed subgroups without specifying it. We say that a subgroup $L$ is a cotoral subgroup of $K\leq G$ if $L \trianglelefteq K$ and the quotient $K/L$ is a torus (i.e. a connected abelian compact Lie group). We write $L\leq_{ct} K$ for this relation.

My question is the following: suppose we fix $H\leq G$ a subgroup, then are the conjugacy classes of the subgroups $K\leq G$ such that $H\leq_{ct}K$ finitely many?

If we look at the examples of rank $1$ then this is true. For $G=S^1$ we have $C_n \leq_{ct} S^1$ for any $n$ but no two $C_n$ and $C_m$ are cotoral. In $G=O(2)$ the dihedral component does not provide any new problem: we can fix dihedral subgroups $D_{2n}$ such that $N_G(D_{2n})=D_{4n}$, hence up to conjugacy we only have the non-trivial cotoral inclusions $D_{2n}\leq_{ct}O(2)$. The subgroup structure of $SO(3)$ is more complicated, but even in this case I could not find a closed subgroup cotorally included in infinitely many non-conjugated subgroups.

I am not so much familiar with compact Lie groups that I can show this should be true in general. For a fixed $H\leq G$ trivially the length of the chain of cotoral inclusions $H <_{ct} K_1 <_{ct} K_2 <_{ct}\dots <_{ct} K_n$ must be finite because at each step we are increasing the rank of the subgroup and this is bounded by the rank of the ambient group $G$. But I cannot see why the subgroups $K$ with $H<_{ct} K$ and $K/H$ of fixed rank should be finitely many up to conjugacy.

I would think that either the claim is false or there is some theorem in the literature which leads to such result.

Comment: For $H=1$ that would mean that $G$ contains only finitely many conjugacy classes of tori. But $G=SU(3)$ has infinitely many classes of one-dimensional tori.

Comment: Yes. An example even more trivial: consider $G=S^1 \times S^1$ and $H=1$, then any $K$ isomorphic to $S^1$ will provide a conjugacy class. But it is easy to see that there are infinitely many copies of $S^1$ in $G$.